# Erro ao verificar se os campos estão vazios!

Tags: android, mobile

Estou tentando verificar se os campos de cadastro do produto estão vazios, provavelmente o erro está na declaração do `if`, que era para está retornando a mensagem de erro:

> "Campos não preenchidos, tente novamente"

Com a aplicação executando, se eu preencher todos os campos do cadastro produto ele funciona perfeitamente, e chega até a tabela no banco, mas se eu apertar o botão cadastrar com os campos vazios era para ele me mostrar a mensagem de erro, mas ao invés disso, o aplicativo trava e reinicia.

```
Process: com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1, PID: 2818
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:539)
at com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1.CadastroProduto$1.onClick (CadastroProduto.java:54)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
2018-11-08 16:13:46.384 492-1756/system_process E/EGL_emulation: tid 1756: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
2018-11-08 16:13:56.703 492-509/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-08 16:16:00.004 492-509/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-08 16:18:00.006 492-509/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-11-08 16:18:46.615 492-1165/system_process E/ActivityManager: Found activity ActivityRecord{4229246 u0 com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1/.TelaLogin t-1 f} in proc activity list using null instead of expected ProcessRecord{60cfefe 
2818:com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1/u0a68}
2018-11-08 16:18:46.643 492-563/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '512a963 com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1/com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1.CadastroProduto (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-11-08 16:18:46.643 492-563/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'fad8f39 com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1/com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1.TelaPrincipal (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-11-08 16:18:46.643 492-563/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'fb3b8a9 com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1/com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1.Produtos (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-11-08 16:18:46.643 492-563/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '324fdd0 com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1/com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1.TelaLogin (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-11-08 16:18:46.833 1168-1315/com.android.launcher3 E/EGL_emulation: tid 1315: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
2018-11-08 16:19:00.004 492-509/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

Essa é a mensagem de erro!

```
public class CadastroProduto extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spnFornecedor, spnUMedida;
EditText edtDescricao, edtCategoria, edtVCusto, edtVVenda, edtEAtual, edtEMinimo;
Button btnNFornecedor, btnCadastrar02;

DBHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cadastro_produto);

    db = new DBHelper(this);

    spnFornecedor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnFornecedor);
    spnUMedida = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnUMedida);

    edtDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDescricao);
    edtCategoria = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCategoria);
    edtVCusto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtVCusto);
    edtVVenda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtVVenda);
    edtEAtual = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEAtual);
    edtEMinimo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEMinimo);

    btnNFornecedor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNFornecedor);
    btnCadastrar02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCadastrar02);

    ArrayAdapter adapterUM = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource (this,R.array.unidade_medida, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spnUMedida.setAdapter(adapterUM);

    btnCadastrar02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Produto produto = new Produto();

            //String fornecedor = spnFornecedor.getSelectedItem().toString();
            produto.setUnidadeMedida(spnUMedida.getSelectedItem().toString());
            produto.setDescricao(edtDescricao.getText().toString());
            produto.setCategoria(edtCategoria.getText().toString());
            produto.setValorCusto (Double.parseDouble(edtVCusto.getText().toString()));
            produto.setValorVenda(Double.parseDouble(edtVVenda.getText().toString()));
            produto.setEstoqueAtual(Integer.parseInt(edtEAtual.getText().toString()));
            produto.setEstoqueMinimo(Integer.parseInt(edtEMinimo.getText().toString()));
            //String unidadeMedida = spnUMedida.getSelectedItem().toString();
            /*String descricao = edtDescricao.getText().toString();
            String categoria = edtCategoria.getText().toString();
            String valorCusto = edtVCusto.getText().toString();
            String valorVenda = edtVVenda.getText().toString();
            String estoqueAtual = edtEAtual.getText().toString();
            String estoqueMinimo = edtEMinimo.getText().toString();*/

            if (edtDescricao.getText().toString().equals(null) ||
                    edtCategoria.getText().toString().equals(null) ||
                    edtVCusto.getText().toString().equals(null) ||
                    edtVVenda.getText().toString().equals(null) ||
                    edtEAtual.getText().toString().equals(null) ||
                    edtEMinimo.getText().toString().equals(null)) {
                Toast.makeText(CadastroProduto.this, "Campos não preenchidos, tente novamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else {

                long res = db.CriarProduto(produto);
                if (res>0){
                    Toast.makeText(CadastroProduto.this, "Produto cadastrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent i = new Intent (CadastroProduto.this, Produtos.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(CadastroProduto.this, "Cadastro invalido, tente novamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Aqui é aonde o mensagem indica o erro, mas certo na linha que diz

> "produto.setValorCusto (Double.parseDouble(edtVCusto.getText().toString())); (linha 54)".

Tem algumas partes de códigos comentadas pois estou testando varias formas.

Answer (score 1):

O erro que você vê nada tem a ver com o salvar no banco, mas sim com os *setters* que está a chamar, que recebem o valor em `Double`, estes:

```
produto.setValorCusto (Double.parseDouble(edtVCusto.getText().toString()));          
produto.setValorVenda(Double.parseDouble(edtVVenda.getText().toString()));
```

Se a `String` passada ao `parseDouble` for vazia, é lançada uma exceção, na forma de `NumberFormatException`. Repare que a própria descrição da exceção lhe diz o problema:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Veja que é mencionado `empty String` ou seja `String` vazia. Quando corrigir este problema os dois `Integer.parseInt` que vem logo abaixo vão dar exatamente o mesmo problema.

[Veja um exemplo simplificado desta exceção no Ideone](https://ideone.com/F6yJHI)

Para contornar o problema tem de verificar se a `String` não é vazia antes de converter. Uma forma simples é:

```
if (edtVCusto.getText().toString().equals("")){
    produto.setValorCusto (Double.parseDouble(edtVCusto.getText().toString()));
}
```

Se quiser evitar o caso de o usuário colocar espaços em branco, pode utilizar o `trim` antes do `equals`:

```
if (edtVCusto.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
    produto.setValorCusto (Double.parseDouble(edtVCusto.getText().toString()));
}
```

Você até já tem o `if` que verifica se os campos todos estão preenchidos mas também não está correto pois testa apenas com `null` e está no local errado, depois dos *setters*. Passando a criação do `Produto` e respetivos *setters* para dentro do `else` do teste dos campos já funciona, mas dada a quantidade de campos que está a testar também pode seguir outro caminho.

Primeiro constrói uma função para validar se todos os campos um array de `EditText` estão preenchidos:

```
private boolean camposPreenchidos(EditText[] campos){
    for (EditText campo: campos){
        if (campo.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Depois no `onCreate` quando quiser validar, chama assim:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...

    btnCadastrar02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText[] campos = {edtDescricao, edtCategoria, edtVCusto, edtVVenda, edtEAtual, edtEMinimo};
        if (!camposPreenchidos(campos)){
            Toast.makeText(CadastroProduto.this, "Campos não preenchidos, tente novamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            //Os seus setters e salvar no banco aqui
        }
    });
}
```

Repare que apenas chama os *setters* e guarda no banco quando tem a certeza que os campos estão todos preenchidos.

Answer (score 0):

Pega todo esse trecho onde está setando os atributo do produto e coloca dentro do else. O erro ocorre ao tentar converter um campo vazio para Double, ja que nao tem valor no Editext
no if verificar se os campos sao vazios com

```
   if(edtDescricao.getText().toString().isEmpty()){

   }
```